# How to avoid this javaservlet login page Security problem

Tags: java, jsp, security, servlets, web-applications

I'm developing a web application in localhost using java. It uses form based authentication. My website's name is web-db-manager. Im using TomEE 7.0 with  jdk 8

this is my code

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><h1>Hello World!</h1></center>
        <form action="Controller" method="post">

            <center>

            <div>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="login">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            </div>
            </center>



</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller.java** (servlet)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Controller"})
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private Authenticator auth = new Authenticator();


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if(auth.match(username, password)) {
            doGet(request,response);
        }
        else {
            request.setAttribute("error", "Unknown user, please try again");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

**Authenticator.java** (Not a servlet)

```
public class Authenticator {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Authenticator(){
        this.username="administrator";
        this.password="admin";
    }

    public Boolean match(String user,String pass){
        if(user.equals(this.username) && pass.equals(this.password)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I works fine with when I give the correct user name and password and it redirects me to the **Welcome.jsp** page where i want to go. And when I have given wrong information it asks me to enter the username and password again. It's OK

But the problem is when I entered the following url manually it redirects me to the Welcome.jsp page **without any username or password**

```
http://localhost:8080/web-db-manager/Controller
```

What is the reason for happening something like this.And what should I do to avoid this security bug

Comment: If you don't want that inside your `doGet()` redirect the page to your login page so that if anyone tries to enter the url manually it will be redirected to login page and inside your doPost function i.e rather than calling doGet() function when credential matches just directly redirect it to the home page

Comment: Silverfang , OH, Thank you very much. Now I got it  :)

Comment: ohhk ! just in case I posted the answer below too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the answer is quite clear. When you manually enter the url It will be treated as GET request and `doGet()` method will be invoked.

If you don't want that,  inside your `doGet()` redirect the page to your login page so that if anyone tries to enter the url manually it will be redirected to login page

Then Inside your doPost function i.e rather than calling `doGet()` function when credential matches just directly redirect it to the home page or welcome page